# Stacked histogram fails for string values in X axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code of a stacked histogram and it works fine, when `FIELD` is numeric. However, when I put `FIELD_str` that instead of 1, 2, 3, ... has `abc1`, `abc2`, `abc3`, etc., then it fails with the error `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects`. How can I substitute (directly or indirectly) the numbers in the X axis with their string values (this is required for the better readability of the chart):

```
filter = df["CLUSTER"] == 1
plt.ylabel("Absolute frequency")
plt.hist([df["FIELD"][filter],df["FIELD"][~filter]],stacked=True,
          color=['#8A2BE2', '#EE3B3B'], label=['1','0'])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

DATASET:

```
s_field1 = pd.Series(["5","5","5","8","8","9","10"]) 
s_field1_str = pd.Series(["abc1","abc1","abc1","abc2","abc2","abc3","abc4"]) 
s_cluster = pd.Series(["1","1","0","1","0","1","0"])  

df = pd.concat([s_field1, s_field1_str, s_cluster], axis=1)
df
```

EDIT:

I tried to create a dictionary but cannot figure out how to put it inside the histogram:

```
# since python 2.7
import collections
yes = collections.Counter(df["FIELD_str"][filter])
no = collections.Counter(df["FIELD_str"][~filter])
```

Comment: It is hard to help you without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @GWW: See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to use barplot instead of histogram, as histogram by definition is for data on numeric (interval) scale, not nominal (categorical) scale. You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

s_field1 = pd.Series(["5","5","5","8","8","9","10"])
s_field1_str = pd.Series(["abc1","abc1","abc1","abc2","abc2","abc3","abc4"]) 
s_cluster = pd.Series(["1","1","0","1","0","1","0"])

df = pd.concat([s_field1, s_field1_str, s_cluster], axis=1)
df.columns = ['FIELD', 'FIELD_str', 'CLUSTER']
counts = df.groupby(['FIELD_str', 'CLUSTER']).count().unstack()
# calculate counts by CLUSTER and FIELD_str
counts.columns = counts.columns.get_level_values(1)
counts.index.name = 'xaxis label here'
ax = counts.plot.bar(stacked=True, title='Some title here')
ax.set_ylabel("yaxis label here")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("stacked_barplot.png")
```

[image: stacked barplot]

Comment: Your previous solution with `T` worked fine for me (otherwise the chart looks weired on the complete dataset): `counts.columns = counts.columns.get_level_values(1)
counts.T.plot.bar(stacked=True,color=['#8A2BE2', '#EE3B3B'])`

Comment: How can I add title and xaxis label in this case?

Comment: I edited answer to add title and xaxis label. You can also create new axis with ordinary `matplotlib` calls, tweak them as you wish and ask `pandas.plot` to use that axis with `ax=…` argument.

Comment: The new solution work either (at least, for me). I managed to avoid transposition of dataframe `count` by choosing the correct order of columns in `groupby`.

Comment: Sorry, what about the title of Y axis? Could you please add it as well.

Comment: Yeah, i did it :)